# How to join the results of two queries in just one table grouped by YEAR and MONTH?

Tags: sql, left-join

I have two tables,`materials_students` and `components_students`. Both of them has a`finished_at` column. `material_student` has a `component_student_id` column.

I need to count the number of components_students and materials_students (Where finished_at id is not NULL), extract month and year from finished_at, group the result by month and year and plot it in just one table, like this:

```
      | Materials  | Components |  Month |  Year
      ---------------------------------------------  
      |   45             3            1     2019
      |   37             6            2     2019
      |   63             8            3     2019
```

I know how to do this for one table only, but dont know how to join the results in just one table.

Find below how I did for one table:

```
FROM materials_students
LEFT JOIN students ON materials_students.student_id = students.id
LEFT JOIN company_profiles ON students.company_profile_id = company_profiles.id
LEFT JOIN companies ON company_profiles.company_id = companies.id
WHERE materials_students.finished_at IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY YEAR, MONTH
ORDER BY YEAR, MONTH
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.

Comment: Hint: `UNION ALL`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best is to assemble a subquery for each case, then join them.

```
select
  ISNULL(M.yy, C.yy) [yy],
  ISNULL(M.mm, C.mm) [mm], 
  ISNULL(number_material_students, 0) [number_material_students],
  ISNULL(number_components_students, 0) [number_component_students]
from (
  SELECT
    year(materials_students.finished_at) yy, 
    month(materials_students.finished_at) mm,
    count(*) number_material_students
  FROM materials_students
  LEFT JOIN students ON materials_students.student_id = students.id
  LEFT JOIN company_profiles ON students.company_profile_id = company_profiles.id
  LEFT JOIN companies ON company_profiles.company_id = companies.id
  WHERE materials_students.finished_at IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY year(materials_students.finished_at), month(materials_students.finished_at)
) M
full outer join (
  SELECT
    year(components_students.finished_at) yy, 
    month(components_students.finished_at) mm,
    count(*) number_material_students
  FROM components_students
  LEFT JOIN students ON components_students.student_id = students.id
  LEFT JOIN company_profiles ON students.company_profile_id = company_profiles.id
  LEFT JOIN companies ON company_profiles.company_id = companies.id
  WHERE components_students.finished_at IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY year(materials_students.finished_at), month(materials_students.finished_at)
) C
ON C.yy = M.yy AND C.mm = M.mm
ORDER BY 1, 2
```

I had to make a `FULL OUTER JOIN` between the subqueries, because there may have been year/months that appear only on materials, but not on components, and vice-versa.

To retrieve the year I use the `ISNULL()` function, so in case year is not filled from the materials subquery, I use it from the components subquery. Similar reasoning applies to all other resulting columns.